# Get problem to understand "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following" Suzuki Abe

Tags: image-processing

I'm confuse with their explanation about definition 1 notation of 4- (8-) and 8- (4-) in [Suzuki Abe paper "Topological Structural Analysis of Digitized Binary Images by Border Following"](http://tpf-robotica.googlecode.com/svn-history/r397/trunk/Vision/papers/SA-CVGIP.PDF) pg 34, and what they mean about NBD and LNBD in pg 35? Is NBD=neighborhood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the paper 4-(8-) refers to the 4 and 8 neighbor connectivity between the two pixels and in the algorithm NBD is the newest border found during the raster scan of the binary image and LNBD refers to the last newest border, NBD and LNBD is stored to obtain the surroundness relation between the borders.

Comment: ahh I see, thanks for your explanation I understand it now